# Searching for keyword in text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, search, text

I have a list of passwords in a text file called "SortedUniqueMasterList.txt". I'm writing a program that takes user input and checks to see if the inputted password is in the list.

Here is my code:

```
Passwords = []

with open("SortedUniqueMasterList.txt", "r", encoding = "latin-1") as infile:
    print("File opened.")
    for line in infile:
        Passwords.append(line)
    print("Lines loaded.")

while True:
    InputPassword = input("Enter a password.")
    print("Searching for password.")
    if InputPassword in Passwords:
        print("Found")
    else:
        print("Not found.")
```

However, every password that I enter returns "Not found.", even ones that I know for sure are in the list.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: can you also provide what a line would look like? and what user input would be?

Comment: Passwords.append(line.strip()) works for me

Comment: @downshift: You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @BrenBarn, alright, although I've seen users get slammed for one-liner fixes so I was just being hesitant

Comment: working on this now, but yeah please print what the lines list ooks like before your while stateent

Comment: @downshift: Well, yeah, you should also explain why it works.

Comment: @BrenBarn, thanks I gave it a shot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading lines in your file, each entry in your `Passwords` list will contain a "new line" character, `'\n'`, that you will want to strip off before checking for a match, `str.strip()` should allow keywords to be found like this:

```
for line in infile:
        Passwords.append(line.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

Something closer to this runs - when you read a file, you can read each line in as an array element. try this let mme know how it goes

```
with open("SortedUniqueMasterList.txt", "r") as infile:
    print("File opened.")
    Passwords = infile.readlines()
    print("Lines loaded.")

while True:
    InputPassword = input("Enter a password.")
    InputPassword  = str(InputPassword)
    print("Searching for password.")
    if InputPassword in Passwords:
        print("Found")
    else:
        print("Not found.")
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that you cannot look for a substring in a python list.  You must loop through the list checking if the substring is found in any of the elements, then determine if it was found or not.

```
Passwords = []

with open("SortedUniqueMasterList.txt", "r", encoding = "latin-1") as infile:
    print("File opened.")
    for line in infile:
        Passwords.append(line)
    print("Lines loaded.")

while True:
    InputPassword = input("Enter a password.")
    print("Searching for password.")
    found = False
    for i in Passwords:
        if InputPassword in i:
            found = True
            break
    if found:
        print("Found.")
    else:
        print("Not found.")
```

Comment: He's not looking for a substring, he's looking to see if the password is in the list of passwords.

Comment: exactly, he needs to get infile to retuurn a list of strings, but is not looking at a single string at any pt

Answer (score -1):

I think this is a problem I've had, maybe it is, maybe it isn't. The problem is called a trailing newline. Basically, when you press enter on a text document, it'll enter a special character which indicates it's a new line. To get rid of this problem, import the module `linecache`. Then, instead of having to open the file and close it, you do `linecahce.getline(file, line).strip()`.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Your diagnosis is correct, but your proposed solution is not the right way to handle it.